# Really big table troubles

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, ltxtable

I have a really big problem here. I have to insert a big table in a document. No matter how I tried to make it smaller, my boss does not want it to be changed. He made it using word, and I have to insert it in latex document. I tried using ltxtable, but it creates 116 errors... yeah, 116...

Here is the code I use for the table :

```
\begin{longtable}{|X|X|X|X|X|}%
\tiny
\hline
Problèmes & Exigences de conception de l'ATL  & Principes de conception de l'ATL & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Approche logicielle d'implantation}\\
\hline
Complexité & Masquer aux développeurs d'applications la connaissance et la complexité du choix des solutions protocolaires à invoquer.\newline Masquer aux développeurs d'applications la complexité d'utilisation des solutions protocolaires qui seront invoquées. & Abstraction Sémantique & \multirow{4}{\hsize}{Approche orientée services} & Approche basée sémantique\\
\cline{1-3} \cline{5-5}
Dépendance & Permettre une adaptation de la solution protocolaire retenue en réponse à une évolution du contexte machine/réseau, ou bien à une modification de l’expression du service requis par l’application, c’est à dire :\newline
\begin{itemize}
  \item être doté d’une capacité d’autonomie dans la prise de connaissance du contexte et de ces évolutions, en plus de celle liée au choix et à la mise en \oe uvre des solutions protocolaires à invoquer;
  \item être doté d’une capacité d’autonomie dans le choix et la mise en œuvre des adaptations de la solution protocolaire en cours;
  \item offrir aux développeurs d’applications la possibilité de modifier les caractéristiques du service requis durant le temps d’exécution de l’application.
\end{itemize} & Abstraction Autonomie & & Approche autonomique\\
\cline{1-3} \cline{5-5}
Manque d'extensibilité & Permettre son intégration au sein de son pool de services et de solutions protocolaires, en vue de la mise à disposition du service correspondant et de l’utilisation de la solution protocolaire. & Extensibilité & & \multirow{2}{\hsize}{Approche basée composants}\\
\cline{1-3}
Manque de configurabilité & Gérer la nature composable des différents protocoles et mécanismes protocolaires, chaque protocole pouvant se voir adjoindre des mécanismes externes. & Configurabilité & & \\
\hline
\caption{Synthèse des problèmes, exigences, principes et approches de conception de l'ATL}
\label{syntheseapproches}
\end{longtable}
```

Which I insert in the main document using :

```
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{Tables/synthese_approches}
```

I know this is crappy. There is a lot of text which is very wide and I don't have much time, unfortunately. A pdf of the "model" made with Word can be found there:

http://homepages.laas.fr/gdugue/bigTable.pdf

I know this problem may get on the nerves of some of you or make you at least raise an eyebrow,  and for this I apologize in advance. Many many thanks for your help, I've been trying to work my way through this for days with no light of hope.

Comment: Did you remember to use UTF-8 input encoding?

Comment: Sympathies. Everything that could possibly be wrong with a table, your boss has done it!

Comment: So in your case it is better to insert it as a pdf image.

Comment: Damn me, I did not notice the table dedicated .tex file did not save in UTF-8. Weird, it should be the default setting but anyway, it's still awfully ugly. I'll try rotate it to landscape or insert it as a pdf in last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses `makecell`, `enumitem`, `ltablex` that combines  tabularx and longtable, and finally `caption` and `babel` (since it's written in French). I don't need `multirow`, since makecell has its own `multirowcell` command, with a simpler syntax and the possibility to use `\\` inside a cell. Please note that the number of rows used by \multirowcell is rather the total number of lines of these rows – not exactly though, for diverse reasons, so that if you change the number of lines you'll have to adapt the exact values.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[margin = 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\def\frenchtablename{Tableau}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font = {sf, small}, labelfont = sc}

\usepackage{ltablex}
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\hsize=.75\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}X}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small\sffamily}m{#1}}

        \begin{document}

{\sffamily\small\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\centering}S|L|>{\centering}S|>{\centering\arraybackslash}S|>{\centering\arraybackslash}S|}%{|S|L|>{\centering}M|>{\centering}S|>{\centering}M|}%
\hline
\thead{Problèmes} & \thead{Exigences de conception de l'ATL} & \thead{Principes \\ de conception \\ de l'ATL} &\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\thead{Approche logicielle \\ d'implantation}}\\
\hline
Complexité & Masquer aux développeurs d'applications la connaissance et la complexité du choix des solutions protocolaires à invoquer.\newline Masquer aux développeurs d'applications la complexité d'utilisation des solutions protocolaires qui seront invoquées. & Abstraction Sémantique & \multirowcell{22}{Approche\\ orientée\\ services} & Approche basée sémantique\\
\cline{1-3} \cline{5-5}
\multirowcell{11}{Dépendance} & Permettre une adaptation de la solution protocolaire retenue en réponse à une évolution du contexte machine/réseau, ou bien à une modification de l’expression du service requis par l’application, c’est-à-dire :%\newline
& \multirowcell{11}{Abstraction\\ Autonomie} & & \multirowcell{11}{Approche\\ autonomique} \\[-3.2ex]
 & \multicolumn{1}{m{0.348\linewidth}|}{%
\begin{itemize}[wide, label =$ \bullet $,leftmargin =1em, nosep]
 \item être doté d’une capacité d’autonomie dans la prise de connaissance du contexte et de ces évolutions, en plus de celle liée au choix et à la mise en \oe uvre des solutions protocolaires à invoquer;
 \item être doté d’une capacité d’autonomie dans le choix et la mise en œuvre des adaptations de la solution protocolaire en cours;
 \item offrir aux développeurs d’applications la possibilité de modifier les caractéristiques du service requis durant le temps d’exécution de l’application.\vskip-2ex
\end{itemize}} & & &
\\
\cline{1-3} \cline{5-5}
\makecell{Manque\\ d'extensibilité} & Permettre son intégration au sein de son pool de services et de solutions protocolaires, en vue de la mise à disposition du service correspondant et de l’utilisation de la solution protocolaire. & Extensibilité & & \multirowcell{5}{Approche\\ basée\\ composants}\\
\cline{1-3}
Manque de configurabilité & Gérer la nature composable des différents protocoles et mécanismes protocolaires, chaque protocole pouvant se voir adjoindre des mécanismes externes. & Configurabilité & & \\
\hline
\caption{Synthèse des problèmes, exigences, principes et approches de conception de l'ATL}
\label{syntheseapproches}
\end{tabularx}}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is very impressive, thank you very much. I'll try it asap. I was about to download a word2latex converter.

Comment: Word2latex surely can't produce such codes. I think it can only use basic latex and perhaps some long-established packages…

Comment: This is great. I only had to make very few changes for it to fit in my document. It's perfect, thanks a lot.